# Radio button input not working in bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am submitting a form containing radio button inputs. It works if I remove the 'class' attribute  from the radio button inputs (or display without the bootstrap template), but not otherwise.

If you [click any star here](http://myhelpinghandonline.com/272/gurnoorproducts.php) and submit, rating is null. Corresponding PHP code to generate HTML form (same in both links): 
test_ratings_curl.php

```js
 <? php
 print('       <form method="post" action="rating_curl.php">
              <span class="rating">');
 $rating = 4;
 $inp_no = 1;
 print('<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="arya" />');
 for ($k = 1; $k <= $rating; $k++) {
   $inp_no = $k;
   $to_print = '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_'.strval($k).
   '" name="rating_input_'.strval($k).
   '" value="rating_input_'.strval($k).
   '" >
                <label for="rating_input_1_'.strval($k).
   '" class="rating-star1"></label>';
   print($to_print);
 }
 for ($j = $inp_no + 1; $j <= 5; $j++) {
   $to_print = '<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_'.strval($j).
   '" name="rating_input_'.strval($j).
   'value="rating_input_'.strval($k).
   '" >
                <label for="rating_input_1_'.strval($j).
   '" class="rating-star"></label>';
   print($to_print);

 }

 print('  </form>
                &nbsp;');
 print('    
        <input type="submit" name="rating_submit">
        </span>'); ?>
```

But [here](http://myhelpinghandonline.com/272/test_rating_curl.php) rating is returned.

(Both have the same HTML):

```html
<form method="post" action="rating_curl.php">
  <span class="rating">
              <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="arya">

              <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1" name="rating_input_1" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_1">
                <label for="rating_input_1_1" class="rating-star1"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_2" name="rating_input_2" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_2">
                <label for="rating_input_1_2" class="rating-star1"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_3" name="rating_input_3" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_3">
                <label for="rating_input_1_3" class="rating-star"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_4" name="rating_input_4" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_3">
                <label for="rating_input_1_4" class="rating-star"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_5" name="rating_input_5" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_3">
                <label for="rating_input_1_5" class="rating-star"></label>
          <input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer">
          
                &nbsp;       (43)         
        <input type="submit" name="rating_submit">
        </span>
</form>
```

Code for extracting POST variables (rating_curl.php):

```js
<? php
extract($_POST);

$rating = null;
if (isset($rating_input_1)) {
  $rating = "1";
}
elseif(isset($rating_input_2)) {
  $rating = "2";
}
elseif(isset($rating_input_3)) {
  $rating = "3";
}
elseif(isset($rating_input_4)) {
  $rating = "4";
}
elseif(isset($rating_input_5)) {
  $rating = "5";
}
print('Inside rating_curl.php<br/>');
print("rating= ".$rating);
print('<br/>');
print('hidden: '.strval($answer));
print('<br/>');
print("name of product = ".$Name);
$ch = curl_init();
$post = 'name='.$Name.
'&rating='.$rating;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'gurnoors.com/rating.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);

print('<br/>Curl Results: <br/>');
print($contents);


?>
```

Conclusion:
As stated by the accepted answer,  value of `label`'s attribute `for` must be the same as `id` of `input`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works:

```
<form method="post" action="rating_curl.php">
              <span class="rating">
              <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="arya">
                <input type="radio" value="rating_input_1" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1" name="rating_input_1">
                  <label for="rating_input_1_1" class="rating-star1"></label>
                <input type="radio" value="rating_input_2" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1_2" name="rating_input_2">
                  <label for="rating_input_1_2" class="rating-star1"></label>
                <input type="radio" value="rating_input_3" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1_3" name="rating_input_3">
                  <label for="rating_input_1_3" class="rating-star"></label>
                <input type="radio" value="rating_input_4" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1_4" name="rating_input_4">
                  <label for="rating_input_1_4" class="rating-star"></label>
                <input type="radio" value="rating_input_5" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1_5" name="rating_input_5">
                  <label for="rating_input_1_5" class="rating-star"></label>
          &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="rating_submit">
        </span></form>
```

You need to check how input's attributes are generated on the page.

Now it looks some weird:

```
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1_1" name="rating_input_" 1"="" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_1">
```

Attribute `name="rating_input_" 1"=""` looks strange.

also value of `label`'s attribute `for` must be the same as `id` of `input`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want radio button (only one select), you need to add every input the same name.

```
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_1" name="rating_input" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_1">

<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_2" name="rating_input" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_2">

<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating_input_3" name="rating_input" onclick="check(this.id)" value="rating_input_3">
```

Comment: 1) Thank you for your the 'only one select'. But then, how can I know which button was clicked while parsing the 'form post'.
2) I cannot get the radio input while parsing the post